# Empty QueryDict in ajax POST query - Django

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, post

I use an ajax **POST** query with data: `{'action':'add'}` in Django template but if I print `request.POST` in **views.py** it shows in console `<QueryDict: {}>`.

But firebug shows `POST 302` and `action=add` or `action=remove` parameters! So I cannot understand why is `<QueryDict: {}>` is empty. Please help.

PS. If I use GET it works fine.

template **show_event.html**:

```
<form id="unfollow" {% if user not in event.users.all %}style="display:none;"{% endif %}>
    <input type="hidden" value="{{ event.id }}" name="remove">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-block">{% trans "Remove from My events"%}</button>
</form>

<form id="follow" {% if user in event.users.all %}style="display:none;"{% endif %}>
    <input type="hidden" value="{{ event.id }}" name="add">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">{% trans "Add to My events"%}</button>
</form>

    $(document).on('submit','#unfollow', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:'/event/follow/{{ event.id }}/',
            data: {'action':'remove'},
            success:function(){
                $('#unfollow').hide();
                $('#follow').show();
            }
        })
    });

    $(document).on('submit','#follow', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:'/event/follow/{{ event.id }}/',
            data: {'action':'add'},
            success:function(){
                 $('#follow').hide();
                 $('#unfollow').show();
            }
        })
    });
```

**views.py:**

```
def follow (request, event_id):
    event = get_object_or_404(Event, id=event_id)
    user = request.user
    print request.POST
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print "post"
        if request.POST['action'] == 'add':
            print "add"
            event.users.add(user)
            event.save()
        elif request.POST['action'] == 'remove':
            print "remove"
            event.users.remove(user)
            event.save()
    return HttpResponse('')
```

**urls.py:**

```
url(r'^event/follow/(?P<event_id>[0-9]+)/$', 'events.views.follow', name='follow')
```

Comment: Is there any `500` status error? the view accepts `counter_id` as kwarg and you are passing `event_id`.. is this the same view?

Comment: @v1k45 Sorry i pasted wrong view, now i edited my question. There is no 500 error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT (2nd: fixing the form markup to match the URL):

Actually, as you have the form complete in your markup, there is a simpler way to do this:

```
var submitHandler = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();

    var $form = $(this);
    var url = $form.attr( "action" );
    $.post(url, $form.serialize())
        .done(function(data) {
            if (data.following) {
                $('#follow').hide();
                $('#unfollow').show();
            } else {
                $('#follow').show();
                $('#unfollow').hide();
            }
        });
};

$(document).on('submit','#unfollow', submitHandler);
$(document).on('submit','#follow', submitHandler);
```

Your markup should read:

```
<form id="unfollow" method="POST" action="{% url 'follow' event_id=event.id %}
      {% if user not in event.users.all %}style="display:none;"{% endif %}>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" value="remove" name="action">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-block">{% trans "Remove from My events"%}</button>
</form>

<form id="follow" method="POST" action="{% url 'follow' event_id=event.id %}
      {% if user in event.users.all %}style="display:none;"{% endif %}>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" value="add" name="action">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">{% trans "Add to My events"%}</button>
</form>
```

Your Django code:

```
@require_http_methods(['POST'])
def follow (request, event_id):
    event = get_object_or_404(Event, id=event_id)
    user = request.user
    action = request.POST.get('action', None)
    following = False
    if action == 'add':
        event.users.add(user)
        following = True
    elif action == 'remove':
        event.users.remove(user)
    else:
        return HttpResponseBadRequest('Unknown action: {}'.format(action))
    event.save()
    return JsonResponse({'following': following})
```

---

Previous answer:

Depending on your jQuery version, `type` might not be available anymore. Try using `method: "POST"` in the AJAX config instead of `type: "POST"`.
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Also, to make your markup more aligned to what you expect in the view and JS, add `method="POST"` to your form element.

---

Side note:

You can handle non existing parameters better by accessing the `QueryDict` via `get()` method like this:

```
request.POST.get('action', None)
```

This will always work (unless `request.POST` is None). If the parameter is not present the default is returned or the second parameter (in this case `None`).

```
request.POST['action']
```

This will fail with a KeyError if `action` is not present.

Comment: Thank you for an answer. Now when i submit the form (with event_id=28 for example) i see a page `http://127.0.0.1:8000/en/event/follow/28/` with _Unknown action: None_ text on it.  And querydict now is: `<QueryDict: {u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'3Ze1vPqPp8QhbZ5fNXuwy39mw5rFL2cS'], u'remove': [u'action']}>`

Comment: The hidden input fields had `value` and `name` confused. I have fixed the form markup sample code in my answer.

Comment: Great! it works now, but after submit i see a blank page with `{"following": true}` or `{"following": false}`. In your example how to submit form without any page refesh and redirecting?

Comment: I've updated my answer. You need to add  `event.preventDefault();` to your submit handler (that should already have been the case? It's in the code in your question).

Comment: Sorry i cannot understand where should i place `event.preventDefault();`? I tried to add this to script but it still redirecting me

Comment: Ok i got it. But how to add csrf token to script like this? Thanks

Comment: Add `{% csrf_token %}` to the form. You must have had something like this already, or the QueryDict in your previous comment wouldn't have included the csrf token.

Comment: Ok its fine now! Great thanks! I added var $form = $(this); and its ok now